# Here maps navigation - trace left behind

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here maps sdk as a navigation solution, all good so far except for this little inconvenient.
While in navigation mode, I see how the calculated route gets rendered around current position in 3D mode, and the current position properly displayed on the map (received in `onPositionUpdated` callback). But if I zoom out the map or just swipe it up to see the whole route, I see how the part of the route left behind is still visible on the map.
I expected to have the route recalculated with every new gps position, and drawn starting from the newly received gps position to the destination point.

This issue doesn't refer to the case where current position goes outside the route (which I know it can be solved with RerouteListener).

Comment: Do you expect the route drawn on the map incrementally shrinks as the user travels the route? If so, this feature is called route eat-up and is currently not supported.

Comment: Exactly, route eat-up, I didn't know how it's called. Ok, at least now I know for sure, you saved me lot of time as I was still looking for a solution :d
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the route drawn on the map incrementally shrinks as the user travels the route? If so, this feature is called route eat-up and is currently not supported.

Currently a feature for a future release.

Comment: Do you have an ETA for this feature?

Comment: Cannot say yet :)