# HERE SDK Color only part of the route

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to color only a part of the route in a different color?
Like drawing a polyline but one that takes the road configuration into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not supported. But if you are wondering about changing only the traveled portion color I previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245575/here-maps-navigation-trace-left-behind).

Comment: Thanks @David. Do you think this is something I might expect to be implemented in the next release? Right now the workarounds i thought about are either draw many polylines, or, the one I favor,  to draw mini routes on top of the existing route so that they appear like overlays. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Using the route polyline to draw a line with foreground overlay will work, but you will most likely need to apply a line simplification algorithm such as douglas puecker when the number of points starts to grow exponentially for long routes.  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm]

Comment: Thanks. It works pretty good with just drawing another route between the points i need and i can control which route object i display on the map with a button and for navigation i use the same route. And for the route eat-up i can use a similar algorithm but reversed so i can color the traveled portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the route geometry to get the list of GeoCoordinates constituing the polyline:

```
geoCoordinates = mapRoute.getRoute().getRouteGeometry()
```

Then you can draw portions of the route in various colors by building new polylines from these coordinates:

```
GeoPolyline geoPolyline = new GeoPolyline();
for (GeoCoordinates point : geoCoordinates) {
    if (<your condition>){
        geoPolyline.add(point);
    }
}
MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline);
mapPolyline.setLineColor(<color>);
map.addMapObject(mapPolyline)
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to say. A polyline is always composed of several straight lines.

Comment: Yes :). Correct. I need something different though, like i described above. The workarounds i found are the ones i wrote in my comment to @david-leong ' s answer. Thanks for the code btw :)