# Is there any way to show traffic information on a specific route only?

Tags: android, here-api

I want to plot traffic information on a specific route only. For example, my route is from Location A to Location B, I want to display traffic data on a particular road only not all roads that are visible to map.

Is there any HERE map API available for this solution?

There is one solution given by HERE map, but It will display traffic information in the whole visible map:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/traffic.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems, there is no "from the box" solution in Here Android SDK API, but anyway you can use workaround and get traffic estimation via [Routing](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/introduction.html) REST API. For example for [Car route from A to B](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/route-from-a-to-b) request like:

`https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ&departure=now`

you got response with tags `"length"` and `"travelTime"` for each leg like:

```
...
"length": 953,
"travelTime": 316,
...
```

and you can calculate speed = length.value / travelTime.value. Also you can use response summary `"distance"` and `"trafficTime"` for whole route:

```
...
"summary": {
      "distance": 953,
      "trafficTime": 316,
...
```

Approach for color only part of the route described in answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44621476/6950238) question:

> You can extract the route geometry to get the list of `GeoCoordinates`
>   constituting the polyline:
>
> ```
> geoCoordinates = mapRoute.getRoute().getRouteGeometry()
> ```
>
> Then you can draw portions of the route in various colors by building
>   new polylines from these coordinates:
>
> ```
> GeoPolyline geoPolyline = new GeoPolyline();
> for (GeoCoordinates point : geoCoordinates) {
>     if (<your condition>){
>         geoPolyline.add(point);
>     }
> }
> MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline);
> mapPolyline.setLineColor(<color>);
> map.addMapObject(mapPolyline)
> ```

by [Teriblus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4655246/teriblus) and that comment:

> ... It works pretty good with just drawing another route between the
>   points i need and i can control which route object i display on the
>   map with a button and for navigation i use the same route. ...

Answer (score 0):

You can to switch off all traffic displaying and switch on only `on route` traffic displaying by following:

```
map.mapTrafficLayer?.setEnabled(MapTrafficLayer.RenderLayer.FLOW, false)                  
map.mapTrafficLayer?.setEnabled(MapTrafficLayer.RenderLayer.ONROUTE, true)
map?.isTrafficInfoVisible = true

mapRoute.isTrafficEnabled = true
```